# ¿Como insertar audios en HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

Encontre esto en un articulo del 2017 pero evidentemente me esta faltando algo.

```
<audio id="mireproductor" src="bat.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<div>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()">Play</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').pause()">Pausa</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').load()">Stop</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').volume += .1">Subir volumen</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').volume -= .1">Bajar volumen</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Que es lo que quieres hacer exactamente? añadirle controles al audio?

Comment: Lo de `evidentemente` será para ti. Los demás **no tenemos ni idea** de lo que pretendes, ni de lo que según tu falla. Te sugiero consultar [El Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help), en concreto revisa [¿ Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y lo que es un [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: Allí está todo lo que necesitas https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio

Comment: Lo evidente es que: `player ≠ mireproductor`, según el id de tu elemento audio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta ponerlo de esta manera, también se recomienda subir el audio en distintos formatos por los navegadores. No se si la ruta que tienes correcta, supongo que si. El javascript no se recomienda ponerlo en linea.
HTML

```
<audio id="player">
    <source src="bat.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    </audio>


<div>
    <button id= 'play' onclick= "play()">Play</button>
    <button id='pause' onclick="pause()">Pausa</button>
    <button id='subir' onclick="subir()">Subir volumen</button>
    <button id='bajar' onclick="bajar()">Bajar volumen</button>
</div>
```

JS

```
<script>

    function play(){
    player.play();
}

function pause(){
    player.pause();
}

function subir(){
    player.volume += 0.1;
}

function bajar(){
    player.volume -= 0.1;
}


</script>
```

Puedes encontrar mas información de métodos de audio y video aquí https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp

Comment: Te falta el `getElement`.

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: Si te funciono, puedes dar la respuesta como correcta. Puede parecer una tonteria, pero ayuda a las demas personas cuando buscan soluciones en esta red. Aparte de que motiva a seguir intentando ayudar. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Para insertar un audio lo único que necesitas es la primera línea.

Con el atributo **autoplay** puedes hacer que se reproduzca solo. Y con **controls** el navegador te brinda una interfaz para controlarlo.

---

En caso que quieras usar tus propios controles, el código que compartiste tiene un pequeño inconveniente.

El ID del reproductor es **mireproductor**, pero en el script intentas acceder a el como **player**. Con cambiar el ID ya estará arreglado.

```html
<audio id="player" src="" controls></audio>

<div>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()">Play</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').pause()">Pausa</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').load()">Stop</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').volume += .1">Subir volumen</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').volume -= .1">Bajar volumen</button>
</div>
```

Aunque funciona, no es la mejor manera de implementarlo. A cada rato usa `getElementById` y el volumen puede salirse del rango 0-1 produciendo un error.

Puedes hacer algo como te propuso @jbort.

Comment: Muchas gracias!